# How to define a variadic function

Tags: function, scheme, arguments, variadic-functions, chicken-scheme

I'm looking for something similar to Javascript's `arguments` array:

```
function parent(){
  child.apply(this.arguments);
}
```

I'm aware of the dot notation for variable argument lengths and also scheme's `apply` function.

This doesn't seem to work as the dot is taken to be the first argument:

```
(define (parent .) 
          (list .))

(parent 1 3 4 6 7)
Error: bad argument count - received 5 but expected 1: #<procedure (array arg-list)>
```

This works but isn't ideal. I'd like to call the function without the extra syntax to define the args list:

```
(define (parent args-list)
     (apply list args-list))


(parent 1 3 4 6 7)
Error: bad argument count - received 5 but expected 1: #<procedure (array args-list)>

(parent `(1 3 4 6 7))
(1 3 4 6 7)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
(define (parent . args-list)
    <do something with args-list>)
```

Use it like this:

```
(parent 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Inside the procedure, all the arguments will be bound to a list named `args-list`. In the above snippet, `args-list` will have `'(1 2 3 4 5)` as its value. This is an example of how variadic functions work in Scheme.

For the sake of completeness, the same mechanism can be used for anonymous functions, too (notice that `args-list` is *not* surrounded by parenthesis):

```
((lambda args-list <do something with args-list>) 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 7):

You want:

```
(define (parent . args) 
   args) ; args is a list
```

Which is infact the 'default' implementation of `list`.

```
(define (list . x) x)
```

The error message when applying `(define (parent . ) ...)` seems wrong, also, the code should not have compiled in the first place as it is invalid syntax. Might imply a bug with the version of Chicken Scheme you are using.